# Is $\lim_n (1/n)\log(x_n)=\lim_n(1/n)\log(x_n+1)$?

Tags: analysis, limits

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(x_n)=L$ with $L<\infty$. My (maybe silly) question is, whether
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(x_n+1)=L?
$$

Sad, but I do not know how to prove/ disprove that therefore please give me some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \log(x_n) = L$, then
$\log(x_n)\sim Ln$ as $n\to\infty$.  Therefore $x_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence
$${x_n\over 1 + x_n}\to 1$$
as $n\to\infty$, provided $L > 0$.

Comment: Does this mean that  $x_n\sim 1+x_n$, thus $\log(x_n)\sim \log(x_n+1)$, so that my question is to answer with yes in case $L>0$?

Comment: @ncmathsadist I took the liberty of inserting the previously missing term $1/n$ from the first limit expression.  I hope that you don't mind.  And +1

Answer (score 3):

Take $x_n=e^{-n}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(x_n)=-1$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(x_n+1)=0$.

Comment: This happens whenever $L < 0$.

Comment: What, if $L=0$?